# Transform plain text input string into XML

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt

I have to pass text values from a `<textarea>` tag, each one in different lengths and separated by spaces, to an XML file, with a template XSLT file and client side transformation.

For this, the input text needs to be transformed into XML like shown in the **example below**:

**Input Text** from a `textarea`:

Ax00100200300400     Phillipe           Waken  Brunn

**Needs to be inserted like the following XML** as response in the same `textarea` as the input text:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MainRequest xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <Request version="1.0">
      <Products>
         <Server xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="">
            </TRX>
               <Number>Ax00100200300400</Number>
            </TRX>
            <Applicant>
               <Name>
                  <Surname>Waken</Surname>
                  <First>Phillipe</First>
                  <Middle>Brunn</Middle>
               </Name>
            </Applicant>
         </Server>
      </Products>
   </Request>
</MainRequest>
```

The expected **process flow** is as follows:

1. Client pastes a plain text in the `textarea`
2. Clicks a button to trigger a function
3. The text content gets transformed into an XML file on the same `textarea`.

Comment: I cannot figure what your question is. Is the XML document you show us part of the input, or is it this result you're hoping to get? If the latter, where exactly is this result supposed to be created? On the client? On a server? Which server, if the HTML is a "*standalone file at the client computer*"? There are more questions here than answers.

Comment: @madLokesh I have rolled back your edit. Please confine yourself to correcting obvious mistakes and improving the formatting, and refrain from trying to read the OP's mind.

Comment: Hi @michael.hor257k the question is implicit at the header: "text string from getElementById to xml via xslt", I edit the question to simplify understanding.

Comment: I have reworded your title and altered the content a bit to highlight your requirement. I have also put the process flow (from the initial version) back into the question because it seems to explain your needs pretty well. Step-wise description of the expectation is always welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the very simple requirement, and the fact that it seems like you want to do all of this in the client (i.e. in a web browser), I'd probably just do this using straight up JavaScript.  For example:

```js
var headerPart = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><MainRequest xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"><Request version=\"1.0\"><Products><Server xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation=\"\"><TRX><Number>";
var surnamePart = "</Number></TRX><Applicant><Name><Surname>";
var firstnamePart = "</Surname><First>";
var middlenamePart = "</First><Middle>";
var footerPart = "</Middle></Name></Applicant></Server></Products></Request></MainRequest>";

var textToParse = $("#textAreaId").val();
var textPieces = textToParse.split(" ");
var xmlToSet = headerPart + textPieces[0] + surnamePart + textPieces[3] + firstnamePart + textPieces[1] + middlenamePart + textPieces[2] + footerPart;
$("#output").val(xmlToSet);
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w9bg048m/)

If you need to add formatting characters in the XML string pieces, go for it (for example, using `\r\n\t` to have a new line with a tab).  I don't really see why you'd use XSLT for this though - JavaScript's text manipulation functions are generally going to be easier to work with, you'll be able to do various logic checks (for example, check to make sure `textPieces` has four members, check to make sure the string isn't too long, etc) and provide immediate feedback to the user about errors, and the XML you're producing is not very complicated (no looping/repeating structures, no complicated template matching requirements).

Comment: OK, works fine, but what if the xml have a hundred of tags?, I have to declare them all as var?

Comment: Yes, but your question wasn't really clear about that being a requirement.  Keep in mind that if it were hundreds of different tags you'd have to declare them all in the XSLT as well...

Comment: And One more question @Dan Field, at the JSFiddle example, if I put 2 or more spaces between one value and another the function can't catch the values...

Comment: Right, that's how `string.split` works in JavaScript.  You'll need to figure out how you want to handle that - check the length of the array after the split and make sure it has the right number of values, see if you can remove extra spaces in a way that makes sense, otherwise validate user input, etc.